# Detecting colors in an Image in sequence using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, color-detection

I am working on a project where I need to recognize colors in sequential order from an Image

I am new to openCv. Help needed. Image here

[image]

Comment: Hi are you able to find solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since I think that you have to recognize colors inside the squares, not all colours in the image, you should first of all detect all squares.

After that for each square it's so easy to recognize the colour since you can have the pixel value information in different color spaces (rgb, hsv and so on).

I can suggest you to read [tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/df8/tutorial_root.html) that you can find in the official documentation before to start, they can be really useful.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this (your image is saved to `color_strip.jpg`), basically you load the file and cut the image into the pieces of the same color, then average over the piece to get the average color:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> img = cv2.imread( 'color_strip.jpg' )
>>> img.shape
(3677, 235, 3)
>>> square_size = 2640 / 10
>>> for i in range(11) :
...     top = i * square_size + 10
...     bottom = top + 160
...     data = img[top:bottom,80:210,:]
...     _ = cv2.imwrite( 'data_%02d.jpg' % i, data )
...     print 'mean color', data.mean(axis=0).mean(axis=0)
... 
mean color [  92.55783654  127.716875    143.74230769]
mean color [  95.17754808  126.11514423  157.42605769]
mean color [  84.09365385  151.56105769  190.28004808]
mean color [  83.29528846  148.21403846  165.08956731]
mean color [  50.76451923  140.88158654  211.09413462]
mean color [  19.91221154  150.03350962  221.26485577]
mean color [  41.71350962  150.38677885  200.61456731]
mean color [ 114.19682692  155.68245192  190.50230769]
mean color [ 106.44120192  160.234375    194.67211538]
mean color [ 106.43980769  148.12759615  102.86701923]
mean color [ 117.02735577  151.62211538  171.19259615]
>>>
```

And you may check the `data_XX.jpg` files to make sure they actually contain the color stripes, and not something else.

A minor detail, the printed results are in BGR format used by OpenCV, you may reorder them if you need RGB or any specific order.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the solution. Actually, i dont need any mean of the colors, I am looking for the colors in an image and output should be rgb values of each color of the image and should be from top to bottom

Comment: @MaheshReddy when you say you don't need mean, do you understand that the color squares are not uniform in color, and depending on which point you sample the color at, you'll get the different result?? taking the mean over the area is one of the ways to mitigate this problem.